# What are the number variations of colors in Material UI (Blue[500], Blue[A100]]?

Tags: material-ui, material-design

I see in material ui each color has the following variations:

```
export interface Color {
  50: string;
  100: string;
  200: string;
  300: string;
  400: string;
  500: string;
  600: string;
  700: string;
  800: string;
  900: string;
  A100: string;
  A200: string;
  A400: string;
  A700: string;
}
```

However, I'm confused what these variations represent. Can anyone help me understand? Here's a link, go to the bottom where it says "Color variations for accessibility":

https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors

Comment: can you provide a link where you see this?

Comment: I Added @dovigz

Comment: @Luuk I saw that, but it doesn't say what the formula is from going from 100 to 200 to 300 etc..

Comment: it seems to be a palette of colors when  you use MUI you can define like this `<HomeIcon style={{ color: green[500] }} />` or `<HomeIcon style={{ color: green[50] }} />` with green being the base of 500 I believe [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-qc9s6)

Comment: graphicdesign.stackexchange.com seems to have an answer on that: [What is the meaning of the prefix “A” in material design color guidelines?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/69470)